# What is a surrogate range and surrogate code in Java?

Tags: java, string, class

I was reading the documentation for Class `Character`.That documentation mentions something about **surrogate range**.
and what is the surrogate code ?
What is the use of surrogate methods like `isSurrogate()`, `isSurrogatePair()`, `isLowSurrogate()`, `isHighSurrogate()`.

Comment: http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode7.0.0/ch03.pdf#G2630

Comment: Unicode symbols, _code points_, number into the 3 byte range, and UTF-16 with two byte chars uses such a pair of chars to reach the full Unicode range in a safe manner. "surrogate"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A surrogate pair is a pair of 16-bit values usind in UTF-16 to encode a Unicode code-point outside of the BMP / plane 0; i.e. any Unicode code-point that is greater than 65535.

The surrogate range is the range of 16 bit values that the two values of a pair come from;

- The high value of a surrogate pair comes from the range D800 through DBFF
- The low value of a surrogate pair comes from the range DC00 through DFFF.

For example: the Unicode code point U+10437 is represented in UTF-16 as the surrogate pair D801 DC37.

For more information, read the Wikipedia article on [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16).

---

> What is a surrogate range and surrogate code in Java?

The two surrogate ranges are described above.

A surrogate code is a code<sup>1</sup> in one of the two surrogate ranges.

---

> What is the use of surrogate methods like `isSurrogate()`, `isSurrogatePair()`, `isLowSurrogate()`, `isHighSurrogate()`.

- `isSurrogate()` tests if a `char` is either a low or high surrogate
- `isSurrogatePair()` tests if a pair of `char` values is a valid surrogate pair
- `isLowSurrogate()` tests if a `char` is a low surrogate value
- `isHighSurrogate()` tests if a `char` is a high surrogate value

The use of these methods is self-evident.  They are used to test `char` values when interpreting UTF-16 code units as Unicode code points.

---

<sup>1 - This could be either a code unit or a code point, depending on the context.  If you have a sequence of 16-bit code-units that constitute a UTF-16 string, then these are code-units.  On the other hand, if you have a sequence of Unicode code-points, then if you were to encounter high and low surrogates in that sequence they would be code points.  However the surrogate code-points are not meaningful as text in that context.</sup>